# Axions and complex fields

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry-breaking, axion

I have been reading on axions and pseudo-Nambu-Goldstone Bosons (pNGBs) and I was wondering the following:

A complex field has two degrees of freedom, meaning that one can write the following non-linear realisation (similar to the coset construction with chiral symmetry breaking):

$$\Phi= \rho e^{i\theta}$$

where $\rho,\theta$ are real field. Moreover, $\theta$ is an axion, as it is shift symmetric: $\Phi(\theta)\sim\Phi(\theta+2\pi n)$ for $n\in \mathbb{Z}$.

The kinetic term of that field is

$$|\partial \Phi|^2=(\partial\rho)^2+\rho^2(\partial\theta)^2.$$

Now assume that $\rho$ has a large v.e.v. We can assume $\rho\simeq v=\text{const}$, and define a canonically normalised field $\bar\theta=\theta/v$. Should the v.e.v. be large enough, $\rho$ decouples and we can focus on an effective approach and consider only the canonically normalised field $\bar\theta$.

If $\Phi$ is a pNGB and breaks the $U(1)$ symmetry through a mass term (e.g. a soft mass term in SUSY theories)

$$V\supset m^2\Phi^2+\text{c.c}\simeq 2m^2v^2 \cos(\bar{\theta}/v),$$

what would would be the mass of $\bar\theta$ in that case? Naively I would define the mass has as

$$m^2_\bar{\theta}=\frac{1}{2}\left.\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial \theta^2}\right|_{\theta~=~0}=-m^2$$

In this case the mass is tachyonic. I would expect that assuming $m^2>0$, even in non-linear realisations, everything should be stable, i.e. $m^2_{\bar{\theta}}>0$. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just expand around one of the correct minima among which $\theta=0$ doesn't belong to, once the perturbation $\Phi^2$ is added. Before adding the perturbation any of $\theta$ would have provided a good minimum (because of the shift symmetry), but with the perturbation turned on only a discrete subgroup of minima survive, namely $\theta=(2n+1)\pi$. The perturbation breaks more than the $U(1)$, it breaks also the discrete shift symmetry you started with, since now only odd integers shifts are respected.  A better parametrization for $\Phi$ is actually $\Phi=-\rho e^{i\phi}$.